# When Excel files can be opened in browser?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

In *open* dialog box (of an *Excel 2010 file*) in path *File > open*, there is a drop-down list for *Open* button. One of them is, *open in browser*. When Excel files can be opened in browser (Web browser, e.g., Chrome) please?

Comment: That feature doesn't seem to be there in 2013. Can you paste a screenshot? Also, what happened when you tried clicking it?

Comment: My Excel is 2010. A screenshot of that open dialog box? In that, the _open in browser_ is grayed out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done a bit of Googling and found this: [Little known techniques for opening Excel files](http://www.accountingweb.com/article/little-known-techniques-opening-excel-files/219981)

Looks like this is only an option if you try to open an *HTML* file through the Excel Open browser.

> **Open in Browser:** This option becomes available when you click once on
>   an HTML file within Excel's Open dialog box. The file you select will
>   appear in your default web browser.

If you want to be able to view a spreadsheet in the browser the best option I can think of is to use either SharePoint or Office 365, though the latter would mean getting a new Office package and the former would require an enterprise license to be able to active Excel Services for browser rendering.

(Also wondering whether Google Docs may be an option)